# Delete the following space

Tags: spacing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 %-------------------------------------------
 %-----accent                       
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
    \usepackage[en-US]{datetime2} % <=======================================
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd> <==================================
  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
 %-------------------------------------------
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=2.0cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
%---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\refname}{Travaux de Recherche}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\ding{228}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{empty}
%------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R|X}
\textsc{Mai} 2016& Participation à la ``2éme Séminaire des étudiants chercheurs en Mathématiques'', Faculté des Sciences de .......\\
&{\color{citeblue}{\ding{43}}} \underline{Communication intitulée}: Kolmogorov .....\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Avr.} 2017& Participation à la
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

> I want to reduce the following space. Also if I want to increase the size of the character, can I replace `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` by `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in using `\color`.

Note the missing `\noindent` in your code. I used `utf8` because so my system is set up.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\geometry{left=2.0cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm}

\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}
\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd>
  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Travaux de Recherche}

\frenchspacing
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R|X}
\textsc{Mai} 2016& Participation à la ``2éme Séminaire des étudiants chercheurs en 
Mathématiques'', Faculté des Sciences de .......\\
&\textcolor{citeblue}{\ding{43}} \underline{Communication intitulée}: Kolmogorov ..... \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\\
\textsc{Avr.} 2017& Participation à la
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I don't see where is the problem. I think it is correct to write `\color{red}` for example or we should write `\textcolor{red}`?

Comment: A `\color` command doesn't start a paragraph, so it should never be the first item in a `p` (or `X`) column entry.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `\newline`, not a new row. I took the opportunity to add some improvements and simplification of the code. Note you should use the `utf8` input encoding nowavadays, for a better portability.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
 %-------------------------------------------
 %-----accent
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
    \usepackage[en-US]{datetime2} % <=======================================
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd> <==================================
  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
 %-------------------------------------------
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{margin=1.0cm, left=2.0cm, showframe}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage{tabularx}
%---------------------------------------------
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\scshape}l}
    %---------------------------------------------

    \renewcommand{\refname}{Travaux de Recherche}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\ding{228}}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \newcommand{\ieme}{\textsuperscript{e}\xspace}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L|X}
    Mai 2016& Participation au ``\,2\ieme Séminaire des étudiants chercheurs en Mathématiques\,'', Faculté des Sciences de .......bla bla bla\newline
    {\color{citeblue}{\ding{43}}} \underline{Communication intitulée}: Kolmogorov .....\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    Avr. 2017& Participation à la
    \end{tabularx}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: utf8 is the default encoding since 2018 : https://www.texdev.net/2018/03/25/latex2e-utf-8-as-standard/

Comment: Oh! yes, I had forgotten it· So many people are still coding `\´{e}` instead of `é`…

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack : put in a `\mbox`

```
&{\mbox{\color{citeblue}{\ding{43}}}}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
 %-------------------------------------------
 %-----accent                       
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
    \usepackage[en-US]{datetime2} % <=======================================
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================
\patchcmd{\DTMenglishordinal}% <cmd> <==================================
  {#1 \DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <search>
  {#1\,\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
 %-------------------------------------------
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{left=2.0cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm}

    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage{sectsty}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citeblue}{rgb}{0.00,0.00,0.60}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=citeblue, citecolor=citeblue, linkcolor=citeblue}

    \frenchspacing
    \sectionfont{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
      \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
%---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
%---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\refname}{Travaux de Recherche}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\ding{228}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{empty}
%------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R|X}
\textsc{Mai} 2016& Participation à la ``2éme Séminaire des étudiants chercheurs en Mathématiques'', Faculté des Sciences de .......\\
&{\mbox{\color{citeblue}{\ding{43}}}} \underline{Communication intitulée}: Kolmogorov .....\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\textsc{Avr.} 2017& Participation à la
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think if I replace `\mbox` by `\text`, it works.

Comment: Please also, if I want to increase the size of the character, can I replace \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} by \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}?

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Comment: Please if the title of the communication is long, it does not work.